# suse broken? Can't find glibc

Tags: opensuse, gcc, suse, glibc, yast

I wanted to install the new postgres beta which is only available from source. On my server there was no gcc installed so I wanted to install gcc. After running yast, gcc 4.3.3 could only be installed through downgrading tonnes of packages. I clicked through all that stuff, hit install and then some instalation failures popped up. After hitting abort I can't enter yast anymore.

`/bin/bash: /lib64/libc.so.6: version`GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by /lib64/libreadline.so.5)`

zypper, rpm are also broken. I must have completly f****d up the server. Is there some repair command to get everything running again? I'm running suse 11.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no repair command. What happened is that your downgrade replaced the version of `glibc` from a current version to an older version, and all of the other programs on your system that link against `glibc` (i.e., *everything* except the packages which were downgraded first) are now unable to find the symbols they need to link and run.

You can repair this system by starting up a rescue system (OpenSUSE 11.1 Live CD, or put the hard disk in another computer), then manually download the correct version of `glibc` rpm, unpack it, and manually place its files into the broken system.

In fact you can do this from almost any Linux operating system that can mount the filesystem of your server. The main thing you need is the `rpm` command, but make sure that the version of `rpm` in the rescue system is new-ish so that it supports the LZMA archive format, which I think was deployed by the time 11.1 was released. The safest way to do this is to use the OpenSUSE / SUSE 11.1 Live CD as the rescue system, and not something weird and old like Ubuntu 8.04 or SUSE 10.

Once you get glibc working again, you can `chroot` into the broken system and re-try or rollback the downgrade, and if you run into any errors, just `exit` from the chroot environment, download the needed packages on the host, and unpack them into the guest.

In fact, it may be easier if you boot up an OpenSUSE 11.1 rescue, to just copy all of the files from `/usr` and `/lib64` from the rescue system, into the broken root volume, overwriting all of your core programs with the original versions (glibc, the kernel, Xorg, and so on). But don't overwrite `/boot` or you'll lose your menu.lst / menu.cfg. And don't overwrite `/etc` or you'll lose fstab, which is important and probably not broken (but it will break if you overwrite it with the version on the rescue CD).

Note that this isn't guaranteed to work. You will probably want to run `zypper up` (as root) in the rescue system BEFORE you do this. This will update all the files in `/usr` and `/lib64` to the latest versions from the updates repository prior to putting them on the server. This provides the best probability that everything will work when you boot into the broken system.

Most likely the answer to your question "suse broken?" is probably "yes", but if you're meticulous and know what you're doing, you can still fix it. Convincing the rpm database of the broken system that everything is ok may prove interesting, however.